# Using "into" or "inside"

Tags: word-choice, expressions, prepositions

which sentence do you prefer?

Alex invited the new visitors inside the house and led them to his parents’ office.

Alex invited the new visitors into the house and led them to his parents’ office.

Comment: Are you asking for a *preference* or whether one or the other is ungrammatical? If so, which one do you think is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither is idiomatic.  The "the house" is superfluous. A native speaker would say "Alex invited the new visitors in and ...",  or "Alex invited the new visitors inside and ..."

Usually "invited ...  in" is sufficient.  "Invited inside" is used more commonly when there is something undesirable about the outside, like the weather. Thus:

```
Alex invited the new visitors in and led them to his parents' office
```

but

```
Alex invited the new visitors inside and put their umbrellas in the stand.
```

Comment: Don't disagree with your alternatives, but "into the house" seems idiomatic, to me. But it may be unnecessary unless you need to be specific about them being invited into the house as opposed to the shop or garage.

Comment: @JamesRandom I agree that it is idiomatic in the right context.